# permission denied in running script

Tags: linux, centos, bash, shell

I am running a script but there is an unusual warning:
This is what happened in my console

```
#whoami
root
#ls -l test.sh
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 1894 Feb  2 01:58 test.sh*
#./test.sh
-bash: ./test.sh: Permission denied
```

Edit:
my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read pass port user ip file; do
  echo "startt------------------------------------" $ip
  ping $ip -c 4
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo $ip ok...
  else
    echo $ip failed...
  fi
  echo "finish------------------------------------" $ip
done <<____HERE
pass  22  root  1.1.1.1  test.txt
____HERE
```

any idea?
thank you

Comment: Try to run it using `strace ./test.sh`. This may give you a hint.

Comment: Works for me on my CentOS Linux system.  I'm guessing selinux is blocking execution.  To disable selinux: `setenforce 0` then try to run the script again.  `/etc/selinux/config` sets whether selinux is enabled at system boot time.

Comment: @samiam I tried setenforce 0 but no result guy

Comment: Try this: `echo 0 > /selinux/enforce`

Comment: @samiam again doesn't work

Comment: Then you will need to put `SELINUX=disabled` in `/etc/selinux/config` and reboot (making sure to comment out anything in that file enabling selinux).

Comment: @samiam disabling SELinux permanently is (almost) never the correct solution.

Comment: @lain I tend to agree, but, then again, "correct" is subjective and relative.  Disabling selinux permanently is most certainly the correct solution when, as one example, running an OpenVZ host.  I also feel it is sometimes better to have it off for new sysadmins, so they have less gotchas when trying to learn the ropes.  (In this Q/A, for example, I tried two ways to turn it off temporarily without success)

Comment: @samiam: The correct thing to do if you suspect SELinux is to look for messages in /var/log/audit/audit.log and take appropriate action. That turning it off with `setenforce 0` didn't solve the problem suggests that the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @Iain To selinux or to not selinux is not an open-and-shut case and there are a lot of admins who prefer to just keep it off, e.g. http://lwn.net/Articles/148160/

Comment: @samiam: You have missed the point which is that SElinux is not proven to be the issue here. There are recognised methods diagnosing SELinux issues and solving the problem within the SELinux framework. It could be an SElinux issue but `setenforce 0` should have fixed it if it was. It could be that the OP has /tmp mounted `noexec` it could be something completely different.

Comment: I used your `/var/log/audit/audit.log` suggestion in a back-and-forth difficult troubleshooting case at unix.sx: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112085/sometimes-dont-have-permission-to-create-new-folders-on-an-ntfs-partition-in-ev/112114#112114 It's a good one and I will use it from now on when I suspect selinux is causing problems.  As an old-school Perl hacker and someone who has had dinner with Larry Wall, I feel very strongly in "there is more than one way to do it" and don't think there is only one "correct" way to do something in *NIX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am running the script in /tmp directory
as you see the result of ls is:

```
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 1894 Feb  2 01:58 test.sh*
```

there is `.` after permissions which indicates that an SELinux security context applies to that file. so I copied test.sh in a directory else...

the problem was solved

I was in a directory where it might be a bad idea for executables to reside

```
ls -l /
drwxrwxrwt.   8 root root  1024 Feb  2 07:44 tmp/
```

Comment: Thanks, I learned something new (I wondered what that trailing dot was)

Comment: You don't say which version of CentOS but I have an out of the box CentOS 6.5 with SELinux enabled. If I create your file in /tmp, and make it executable it runs just fine. That you copied your file elsewhere and it works does not prove SELinux is involved. the `setenforce 0` command should have enabled permissive mode, that this didn't solve the problem also suggests SELinux is not involved. You should check /var/log/audit/audit.log for AVC denied messages relating to your issue to prove SELinux is involved.

Comment: @ samiam your welcome

Comment: @Iain I have centos 6.5 ...why negative? what I understand: "I was in a directory where it might be a bad idea for executables to reside"  may be something happend with my /tmp..This is my tmp output (drwxrwxrwt.   8 root root  1024 Feb  2 07:44 tmp/)

Answer (score 1):

im guessing it has do with SELINUX. You are able to check the status with simply typing `sestatus`

Comment: If you read the extensice comments above the OP setenforce 0 and the problem didn't go away.